# How do I use services on server that does not support CORS?

Tags: 6, services

I am using Drupal 6 for my current website. I have confirmed that the server(Pantheon) running my Drupal 6 website on nginx does not support CORS as of now.

I want to interact with this site using services from a Sencha app. If I send a post request to this site from sencha app, the Post method is converted to OPTIONS and is never converted back to Post on the server side. Due to this, no post request is completed. The sam is the case with get request too. However, if I use $.get() method, the get works perfectly. But there is no solution visible to me for post method.

Here is the sencha code making rest call to Drupal 6 site:

For GET

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        scope:this,
                        url: 'http://test.dabeastv2.gotpantheon.com/disk/node',
                        method: 'GET',
                        //params: param,
                        disableCaching: false,
                        crossDomain:true,
                        headers: {"content-Type":"application/json"},
                        success: function (response) {
                            var responseJson = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                            console.log(responseJson);
                            Ext.Msg.alert("Question Received", "We shall get back to you soon.");
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            Ext.Msg.alert("Error","Get failed");
                        }
                    });
```

For POST

```
   Ext.Ajax.request({
                        //scope:this,
                        url: 'http://test.dabeastv2.gotpantheon.com/disk/node',
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {"content-Type":"application/json"},
                        params: param,
                        disableCaching: false,
                        success: function (response) {
                            var responseJson = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                            console.log(responseJson);
                            Ext.Msg.alert("Question sent", "We shall get back to you soon.");
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            Ext.Msg.alert("Error","Post failed");
                        }
                    });
                    console.log(CONTENT_HOST);
```

I have following big issues :

1. As far as I know, if CORS is not enabled, then one can use jsonp for post requests. But I dont know the exact method of using JSONP.
2. How to keep a check on the method conversion when a get/post call is sent using Ext.js from sencha app. By this, I mean how to keep a check either on the server side or on the client side that the requested method reaches as GET or POST and not as OPTIONS.

To say that this is not by large a server specific issue is that Drupal does the same with secha requests on localhost as well. If on localhost, the requested OPTIONS request is not converted back to POST or GET, then this has something to do with Services and Rest Server on Drupal 6 too.